# rdepends stops on virtual packages

Tags: apt, apt-offline

I am working to create an offline repository for a system that does not have internet access.  One of the first packages I am downloading for this system is the apt-offline package.  I am using the command below and am running into the issue "Can't select candidate version as it has no candidate" for two of the dependencies, `debconf-2.0` and `python-argparse`.

```
@RU03:~/a$ sudo apt-get download $(apt-rdepends apt-offline | grep -v "^ ")
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Can't select candidate version from package debconf-2.0 as it has no candidate
E: Can't select candidate version from package python-argparse as it has no candidate
```

I learned that these are both virtual packages, and reading the rdepends man page, one of the bugs state that it does not display information about virtual packages(I'm assuming that is why I am getting the error?)

How can I work around this error to download the apt-offline package for the offline repository I am creating?

Is there a better/faster/more efficient way to download this package, and then install it on my offline repository?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This guy has an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1137335/197572), but haven't tried it.